# Custom TS multi-file source filter for DirectShow

Tags: filter, directshow

I'm having problems writing a custom DS source filter to play a TS stream that was dumped to multiple files. [ed: The point being to re-play a continuous stream from these separate files]

First I tried modifying the Async file sample: no go - the data 'pull' model seems to put all the controlling logic in the splitter filter so I couldn't trick it into believing I have a 'continuous' stream.

So then tried modifying the PushSource desktop sample: it appears we have to babysit the MPEG demuxer this way to create its output pin, parsing data myself to get IDs etc.  I managed to get GraphStudio to auto-wire up something (using a strange DTV-DVD decoder) but it doesn't play anything despite the source filter pushing the right data downstream.

Does anyone have experience in this area to help/suggest anything?

Comment: what do you mean with "controlling logic in the splitter filter"? And why is it a problem to create the output pins of the demux filter yourself?

Comment: I mean the splitter filter controls the whole process, with the source filter seemingly having no control (so I can't fake a continuous stream that way).
It's not so bad creating the pins but other splitters can handle it on their own / do it dynamically when the data starts flowing?
Please correct me if my conceptions are wrong - I'm new to DShow!

Comment: I created a filter doing something similar (but not reading from a file), I have to look tomorrow for the details. But if I remember well, it should be treated like a continuous stream if you don't provide a seek interface. I know the PIDs and format of the audio and video I need, so I create output pins on the demux filter myself. I use ffdshow to decode audio+video. In some situations I also use a commercial push-demultiplexer filter, but I don't know if a free version exists. Hoping to have more information tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks Wimmel.  I have good commercial filters on my system (Elecard) but the pins never connect in the case of my custom filter even though the types seem as if they should match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you found a solution to your problem, now?

I am writing a similar *DirectShow* filter, currently for playing only one file, but I think that modifying it for playing several files should not be a problem.

I built this filter starting from the "**Push Source Bitmap**" filter, but I had to make a lot of changes on it.

I also had to build the graph using an application that I wrote (so not using **GraphEdit**), connect the "**Mpeg-2 Demultiplexer**" to the new filter, add one **PSI** output (mapped to **PID 0** = **PAT**) and the "**MPEG-2 Sections and Tables Filter**" connected to this **PSI** output.

After that, I used the "**MPEG-2 Sections and Tables Filter**" for reading the **PAT** table and the **PMT PIDs** defined inside it. Next, I mapped also all **PMT PIDs** to the same "**MPEG-2 Sections and Tables Filter**", and I parsed the **PMT** tables for knowing Elementary Streams **PIDs** and media types, and next I created one video output and one audio output based on these informations (there may be more than one audio + video streams, but at the current step I retain only the first one). Note that this needs to run the partial graph temporarily in order to be able to parse tables, and after to stop it in order to be able to create the video and audio output pins (with the proper media types) and connect decoders and renderers.

In addition to that, I have an information that I you could find interesting: it appears that when connected, the "**Mpeg-2 Demultiplexer**" searchs the graph for a filter exposing the "**IBDA_NetworkProvider**" interface, and if found, it registers itself to it using the **IBDA_NetworkProvider::RegisterDeviceFilter** method.

I think that you could use this for detecting the "**Mpeg-2 Demultiplexer**" filter insertion into the graph (by exposing the "**IBDA_NetworkProvider**" interface from your filter), and try to make the above operations from your source filter, thus allowing to use your filter inside **GraphEdit** and expect the "**Mpeg-2 Demultiplexer**" to be baby-sat from this filter without worrying to build an application around for doing these operations.

Gingko

Comment: I managed to get something playing after researching the PIDs a bit more, though it only plays the first few seconds, so now looking at why.
This info is interesting - I'll look into it.

Comment: Of course I suppose that you properly parse the PCR clocks timestamps into your source TS stream and use them for not having the file playing too quickly?

Comment: Thanks Gingko - I got MPEG2 stuff playing ok, but yes: MPEG4 plays stupidly fast whatever I spec for the bitrate/frametime (had to cut & paste MP4 GUIDs from graphedit!).  Presume I'd have to restrict pushing samples out as per the timestamps?
More stuff to read up on..!

Comment: Hi @MGB. This is what I do. I parse the samples for finding the ones containing a **PCR** (restricted to the ones for one PID), and each time that I find one, I wait for the corresponding time before pushing (using `CBaseReferenceClock::AdviseTime`, `CAMEvent::Wait` and `CBaseReferenceClock::Unadvise`).
_(sorry for the delay before answering, what I have problems to find is how to be email notified about replies here!)_

Comment: Hi Gingko. Likewise I missed this comment too :)
Had some trouble decoding PCR - end up with a value more similar to the PTS - accurate info on decoding TS is rare!  Was sleeping the thread, will try the clock stuff thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created a TS source filter which reads a network stream. So that is continuous too, but I difference to reading from a file is, that a network stream automatically gives me the correct speed. So I think you should be able to use a similar approach.

I have based my filter on the FBall example from de dx sdk.

The filter derives from `CSource`, `IFileSourceFilter`, `IAMFilterMiscFlags` and `ISpecifyPropertyPages`. The output pin derives just from `CSourceStream`.

If you have problems decoding the audio/video, maybe first try a simple mpeg-2 stream, for example from a DVB source. And make sure you have a decoder installed and it accepts that format. (for example ffdshow has mpeg2 decoding turned off by default).

Comment: Ah I looked at the ball sample before, but thought the pushsource one a closer fit.